# Узнать какое приложение запущено в полный экран

Tags: c#, windows

Есть список процессов

```
Process[] processes = GetAllProcesses();
```

Как мне определить, какое из них **сейчас** отображается в полный экран без панели задач (например запущенная игра)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, [In, Out] ref RECT rect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    public static bool IsForegroundFullScreen()
    {
        return IsForegroundFullScreen(null);
    }

    public static bool IsForegroundFullScreen(Screen screen)
    {
        if (screen == null)
        {
            screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
        }
        RECT rect = new RECT();
        GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(null, GetForegroundWindow()), ref rect);
        return new Rectangle(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top).Contains(screen.Bounds); 
    }
```

Код взят с: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744720/4423545

Искал по словам "c# find fullscreen app"

Comment: Это, конечно, здорово, но мне нужно знать какой именно процесс открыт на весь экран, а не сам факт этого

Comment: Окей, додумался передавать MainWindowHandle процесса вместо GetForegroundWindow()